# Как сделать передвижение на WASD в Python Pygame?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame, спрайт, move

```
    if player_hide or player_stop == False:
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: # 260 75

            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.mod == pygame.KMOD_SHIFT:
                player_rect.x += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_left.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += 5
                if player_rect.collidepoint(flowey_rect.center):
                    player_rect.x += 5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        player_stop = True
                        flowey_render = True
                        time.sleep(2)
                        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                            player_stop = False
                            flowey_render = False
                        
                            
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player_rect.x += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player_right.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.x += -5
                if player_rect.collidepoint(flowey_rect.center):
                    player_rect.x += -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        player_stop = True
                        flowey_render = True
                        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                            player_stop = False
                            flowey_render = False
                        
                    

            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player_rect.y += -5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                     HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                     player_rect.y += 5
                if player_rect.collidepoint(flowey_rect.center):
                    player_rect.y += 5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        player_stop = True
                        flowey_render = True
                        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                            player_stop = False
                            flowey_render = False
                                    

            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player_rect.y += 5
                player_surf = pygame.image.load("images/player.gif")
                player_surf.set_colorkey((255, 255, 255))
                if player_rect.collidepoint(item_rect.center):
                    HEALTH = HEALTH + 1
                    player_rect.y += -5
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        player_stop = True
                        flowey_render = True
                        if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                            player_stop = False
                            flowey_render = False
    
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Создайте, пожалуйста, минимальный пример кода с демонстрацией проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Замените `pygame.K_LEFT`, `pygame.K_RIGHT`, `pygame.K_UP` и `pygame.K_DOWN` на `pygame.K_a`, `pygame.K_d`, `pygame.K_w` и `pygame.K_s` соответственно

Comment: Ладно попробую...

Comment: Блин, не работает. Жму на wasd не работает Caps lock выключен, на анг. языке было.

Comment: До этого я делал из интернета

Comment: Работали только стрелки(кроме shift, space и т.д)

Comment: @БогданИовенко Если стрелки до сих пор работают, значит вы код не перезапустили)

Comment: нет. Код я запустил

Comment: @БогданИовенко Как по вашему могут работать стрелки если мы убрали их из условия?

Comment: У меня в условии есть передвижение по стрелкам. Вы меня не поняли